# scala.. parse a message into various fields

Tags: scala, layout

In Scala, I want to parse each message (of length=20) into individual units. The message will be appended to the end of previous message without a newline character. I tried the below, but any optimizations and improving performance are welcome

```
/* Length.. id=3,name=5,city=8,port=3,indicator=1 */

def layout(rec:String) = { 
val id=rec.take(3)
val name=rec.drop(3).take(5)
val city=rec.drop(3+5).take(8)
val port=rec.drop(3+5+8).take(3)
val ind=rec.drop(3+5+8+3).take(1)
println(id,name,city,port,ind) 
}

val messages="101Jim  Portland990Y102JamesHouston 990X103John Boston  880Y" 
messages grouped(20)  foreach { x => layout(x) } 


In REPL, 

scala> :load work.scala
Loading work.scala...
layout: (rec: String)Unit
messages: String = 101Jim  Portland990Y102JamesHouston 990X103John Boston  880Y
(101,Jim  ,Portland,990,Y)
(102,James,Houston ,990,X)
(103,John ,Boston  ,880,Y)

scala>
```

Answer (score 5, accepted):

You can do this quite nicely with a regular expression:

```
val messages = "101Jim  Portland990Y102JamesHouston 990X103John Boston  880Y"

val RecordPattern = """(\d{3})(.{5})(.{8})(\d{3})(.)""".r

val records = messages.grouped(20).map {
  case RecordPattern(id, name, city, port, ind) => (id, name, city, port, ind)
}
```

And then:

```
scala> records.foreach(println)
(101,Jim  ,Portland,990,Y)
(102,James,Houston ,990,X)
(103,John ,Boston  ,880,Y)
```

This is also likely to perform better than splitting the string using the collections operations like `drop` and `take`, but the difference will be small, and the primary advantage is clarity.

Comment: ..@Travis.. Thanks for the solution. Suppose if the messages are coming in ebcdic format, i.e from Mainframe system. How do I read it in ebcdic and convert into ascii?.

Comment: @stack0114106 That should really be a separate question. :)